# djangocms KeyError: u'__module__'

Tags: django, django-cms

Running djangocms according to this details: [doc.django-cms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html)
in do all the details and when i want tu run the djangocms i got `KeyError: u'__module__'` error

The result of `pip freeze` is:

```
cffi==1.6.0
cryptography==1.3.2
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.6
django-classy-tags==0.7.2
django-cms==3.2.5
django-formtools==1.0
django-i18nurls==0.7
django-mptt==0.8.4
django-sekizai==0.9.0
django-treebeard==4.0.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.1.1
djangocms-installer==0.8.8
enum34==1.1.2
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.1
ipaddress==1.0.16
louis==2.6.5
MySQL-python==1.2.5
netsnmp-python==1.0a1
numpy==1.11.0
packaging==16.7
paramiko==2.0.0
pexpect==4.0.1
ply==3.8
ptyprocess==0.5.1
pwquality==1.3.0
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycparser==2.14
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.20.0
pyparsing==2.1.4
pytz==2016.4
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.2
team==1.0
Terminator==0.98
Twisted==16.1.1
tzlocal==1.2.2
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

error:

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0xb66ed33c>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djang/util/autoreload.py",      
line 93, in wrapper
   fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/command/runserver.py", line 98, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 35, in <module>
class Page(six.with_metaclass(PageMetaClass, MP_Node)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 566, in with_metaclass
return meta("NewBase", bases, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/metaclasses.py", line 17, in __new__
return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 78, in __new__
module = attrs.pop('__module__')
KeyError: u'__module__'
```

i upgrade the six app and decrease the version of django to 1.6
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs you linked to](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html) say it requires Django 1.6.9 or later, so you need to upgrade. The final release of 1.6.X was 1.6.11:

```
pip install django==1.6.11
```

Django 1.6.X is no longer supported so does not receive security fixes. You should upgrade your application to a supported version as soon as possible. The current Long Term Support release is 1.8.X.

Comment: the version of some app that was describe that i must use this version of django and other app, if i upgrade them, is the versions of the app are match?

Comment: I can't tell you whether it will work if you upgrade to 1.6.11, but it seems pretty clear in the docs that it won't won't work with 1.6. Upgrading to 1.7 and then 1.8 will be trickier, you will probably have to make several changes and upgrade other apps at the same time.